# Receiving a string value from client to server

Tags: php, android, api, file, yii2

I am working on `Android` along with `yii-2 php`. From my `app` I am sending some photos in a file using an api call. Along with it I am sending a reference number as shown below.

```
@Multipart
@POST("installation/photo/save")
Call<ApiResponse> uploadImage(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Part("ref_no") RequestBody ref_no, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

The call is initialized as shown below

```
Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getClient();

RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file.getName(), requestFile);

RequestBody ref_no = createPartFromString("<ref_no>");

ref_no = createPartFromString(installationDetails.getReferenceNo());

Call<ApiResponse> call = retrofitInterface.uploadImage("Bearer " + Common.getAuthKey(mContext),ref_no, body);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        Log.d(TAG, response.body().getStatus());

                        if (response.body().getStatus().equals("OK")) {

                            snapManager.updateSnapStatus(AssetsManagementContract.SnapEntry.COLUMN_SITE_SNAP, snap.getSnapName(), Constants.SNAP_SYNCED);
                            Intent broadcastSyc = new Intent();
                            broadcastSyc.setAction(Common.GetSyncImageAction());
                            broadcastSyc.putExtra("STATUS", true);
                            mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcastSyc);
                            sendImage(mContext);

                        }
                        else{
                            snapManager.updateSnapStatus(AssetsManagementContract.SnapEntry.COLUMN_SITE_SNAP, snap.getSnapName(), Constants.SNAP_CLOSED);
                        }

                    } else {
                        snapManager.updateSnapStatus(AssetsManagementContract.SnapEntry.COLUMN_SITE_SNAP, snap.getSnapName(), Constants.SNAP_CLOSED);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error");
                    }
                }
```

**Working of app**

1. User note down the details of installation and take pictures
2. On closing the form two API's are called 
   i) API to save/upload installation data to server
   ii) API to save/upload images to the server.

The images are uploaded when the Installation API response is returned `OK`.

**OkHttp Log**

When the images are pushed to the server below is the call in `ok http`

```
--> POST http://ip:port/api/web/v1/installation/photo/save
01-31 08:34:14.723 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=704cd1e5-e4d5-4d2e-be63-81f5fe3f1aef
01-31 08:34:14.723 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 116027
01-31 08:34:14.724 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer key
01-31 08:34:14.745 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: --704cd1e5-e4d5-4d2e-be63-81f5fe3f1aef
01-31 08:34:14.747 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ref_no"
01-31 08:34:14.748 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
01-31 08:34:14.748 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
01-31 08:34:14.754 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 15
01-31 08:34:14.755 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: 28372250046142R //this is reference number
01-31 08:34:14.755 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: --704cd1e5-e4d5-4d2e-be63-81f5fe3f1aef
01-31 08:34:14.755 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file"; filename="28372250046142R_1517369623_site_1.jpg"
01-31 08:34:14.755 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data
01-31 08:34:14.755 5762-6086/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 115567
```

**Server Side**

At server side below is API code through which images are saved.

```
public function actionSavephoto()
{
    try {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($_FILES as $f) {
            $dd = pathinfo($f['name']);
            if (!isset($dd['extension']) || !in_array($dd['extension'], array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
                return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'uploaded_files' => $count, 'message' => 'Invalid File'];
                break;
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($f['tmp_name'], Installations::UPLOAD_FOLDER . $f['name'])) {
                $count++;
                return ['status' => 'OK', 'uploaded_files' => $count];
                break;
            } else {
                return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'uploaded_files' => $count];
                break;
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception $x) {
        return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'message' => $x->getMessage()];
    }
}
```

The response after `var_dump($dd)` below is the response that generates.

```
array(4) {
  ["dirname"]=>
   string(1) "."
   ["basename"]=>
   string(37) "28372230019211U_1517370655_site_1.jpg"
   ["extension"]=>
     string(3) "jpg"
   ["filename"]=>
   string(33) "28372230019211U_1517370655_site_1"
  }
```

In response there is no `reference number`. How can I get the reference number at server side?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your response format is not correct.

Comment: Basically response includes the details of `file`.

Comment: " string(37)" why are sending reference number like this, make another field for reference inside JSON object

Comment: @farhana the response is ok. I just want to get `reference number` at server side. Whether to add in the file or just passing it from app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is `$_POST['ref_no']` present at server side after the call.